# Связанный DropdownListFor asp.net mvc framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Всем привет, у меня есть 2 связанных списка: 1 - список авто, 2 - исходя из того какое авто выбрано выводится модель. Вывожу связанный список в представлении подобным образом:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CarId, ViewBag.Autos as SelectList, new { id = "NameAuto", @class = "chosen", @style = "width: 285px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelCar, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
             <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ModelAutoId, ViewBag.ModelAutos as SelectList, new { id = "ModelAuto" })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelCar, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
             </div>
        </div>
```

Так же использую в представлении ajax, код данный:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
 
        $('#NameAuto').change(function()
        {
            // получаем выбранный id
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItems")/' + id,
                success: function (data) {
 
                    // заменяем содержимое присланным частичным представлением
                    $('#ModelAuto').replaceWith(data);
                }
            });
        });
    })
    </script>
```

Контроллер:

```
public ActionResult GetItems(int id)
        {
            return PartialView(context.ModelAutoes.Where(x=>x.CarId == id).ToList());
        }
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult RegisterAuto()
        {
                int selectAuto = 1;
                SelectList autos = new SelectList(context.Cars, "Id", "NameAuto", selectAuto);
                ViewBag.PaymentMethodType = new SelectList(this.context.PaymentMethods, "Id", "PrepaymentType");
                ViewBag.Autos = autos;
                SelectList models = new SelectList(context.ModelAutoes.Where(x=>x.CarId == selectAuto), "Id", "NameAutoModel");
                ViewBag.ModelAutos = models;
                return View();
        }
```

Так же частичное представление для вывода связанного списка GetItems:

```
@model IEnumerable<WP1.Models.ModelAuto>
<select id="ModelAuto" name="ModelAuto">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.NameAutoModel</option>
    }
</select>
```

Проблема в том, что при записи в бд всех данных, CarId корректно записывается в бд, но у ModelAutoId приходит значение как null, то есть ничего не записывается. Можете подсказать в чем проблема?

Сущность авто:

```
public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Название авто")]
        public string NameAuto { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegisterAuto> registerAutos { get; set; }
        public Car()
        {
            registerAutos = new List<RegisterAuto>();
        }
```

Так же сущность Модель Авто:

```
public class ModelAuto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? CarId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CarId")]
        public Car Car { get; set; }
        public string NameAutoModel { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegisterAuto> RegisterAutos { get; set; }
        public ModelAuto()
        {
            RegisterAutos = new List<RegisterAuto>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите код в котором у вас описаны сущности (или классы) Авто и Модель Авто.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak ответ

Answer (score 0):

1. Сначала нужно создать корректные модели для двух сущностей, и аннотацию для этих классов. Но я не понимаю из вашего объяснения, какой тип связи этих двух сущностей. Исходя из реальности, может быть множество конкретных экземпляров автомобилей, одной модели. Поэтому скорее всего все должно выглядеть так, для модели:

   ```
    public class ModelAuto {[Key] public int Id { get; set;} [Required] public string NameAutoModel {get; set;} }
   ```

для конкретного Авто:

```
public class Car {
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int ModelAutoId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("ModelAutoId")]
  public virtual ModelAuto ModelAuto { get; set; }

 }
```

2. Создать миграцию в БД и проверить взаимосвязь таблиц.
3. Создать ViewModel c которой можно работать для создания CRUD -операций для Авто

`public class CarVM {public Car Car {get; set;} public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ModelSelectList {get;set;}}`

4. После этого настраивать Представления и Контроллеры для дальнейшей работы.

Вот в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky) решается аналогичная проблема для Товаров и Категорий, к которым относятся конкретные Товары, на ASP.NET Core MVC.